# Conversion From Apex Trigger to Apex Class

Tags: apex, trigger

I created two different triggers, one for `Object1__c` (Parent) and one for `Object2__c` (Child). These triggers just follow the requirement wherein for every created Object1__c and Object2__c records, another set of Parent-Child records `Object3__c` (Parent) and `Object4__c` (Child) will be created also.

Note: Object1__c and Object2__c are both inserted at the same time through another apex class.

`Trigger1` maps and inserts fields from `Object1__c` to `Object3__c`

`Trigger2` maps and inserts fields from `Object2__c` to `Object4__c`

I don't have any problem with this. In fact, all triggers are working totally just fine.

But I've found out that putting all the logic inside apex triggers is not a best practice. Someone suggested to put all the logic inside an apex class, and then call its methods inside an apex trigger. I am not so sure on how to do this, and I am also still confused on how to get this done.

Meanwhile, here are the two apex triggers I've created:

**Trigger1**

```
trigger createObject3 on Object1__c (after insert) {

    List<Object3__c> obj3List = new List<Object3__c>();  

    if(Trigger.IsInsert) { 

         for(Object1__c o1 : Trigger.New) {

            Object3__c obj3form = new Object3__c();

            if(o1.Id != null) {

                obj3form.Name = o1.Field1__c;
                obj3form.Field3__c = o1.Object1__c; 
                obj3form.Field4__c = o1.Field4__c;
                obj3List.add(obj3form);

            }    
        }

        insert obj3List;

    }

}
```

**Trigger2**

```
trigger createObject4 on Object2__c (after insert) {

    List<Object4__c> obj4List = new List<Object4__c>(); 

    Object1__c form1 = [SELECT Id, Field1__c FROM Object1__c WHERE Id =: Trigger.New[0].Object1__c];

    List<Object3__c> form3 = [SELECT Id FROM Object3__c WHERE Name =: form1.Field1__c];

    for(Object4__c f4 : Trigger.New) {

        if(f4.Id != null) {

            Object4__c f4item = new Object4__c();
            f4item.Object3__c = form3[0].Id;
            f4item.Some_field__c = f4.Some_field__c;
            obj4List.add(f4item);

        }

    }

    insert obj4List;

}
```

Comment: Handling the [bulk case correctly](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code) would be a higher priority than moving the logic out to a class: indexing just the first item `[0]` is an indicator that the logic is broken in the bulk case. The term "best practice" can be misleading in that it suggests an absolute truth: in reality what is best to do involves various tradeoffs. For your two triggers, I don't think the loss of [cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) of introducing a class is countered by any benefit.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at Kevin O'Hara's post and framework in this case:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices
https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework

Please note, you don't have to use a trigger handler framework. But it is a good practice though and will give you a brief idea on how to isolate business logic from trigger.

I will explain the code based on Kevin's framework. In general, your trigger will look like this:

```
trigger Object1Trigger on Object1__c (after insert) {
    (new TriggerHandlerObject1()).run();
}
```

And in your TriggerHandlerObject1 Class:

```
public class TriggerHandlerObject1 extends TriggerHandler
{
    public TriggerHandlerObject1() 
    {

    }

    public override void afterInsert()
    {
        createObject3();
    }

    private void createObject3() 
    {
        List<Object3__c> obj3List = new List<Object3__c>();  

        if(Trigger.IsInsert) { 
             for(Object1__c o1 : (List<Object1__c>)Trigger.New) {
                Object3__c obj3form = new Object3__c();
                if(o1.Id != null) {
                    obj3form.Name = o1.Field1__c;
                    obj3form.Field3__c = o1.Object1__c; 
                    obj3form.Field4__c = o1.Field4__c;
                    obj3List.add(obj3form);
                }    
            }

            insert obj3List;
        }
    }
}
```

There are many benefits of doing this if you read other posts about it. Hope this code sample gives you a brief idea.

Comment: what is `extends TriggerHandler` for?

Comment: @Gaynerys It is the TriggerHandler base class in Kevin's framework. What it basically does it providing you with separate methods for different scenarios(insert, update), avoid infinite loop, provide the functionality to bypass trigger and some other basic functionalities. You can choose not to use it and write your own version. But since every trigger has some basic features, it is nice to have a base class.

Comment: Can i also use same `TriggerHandlerObject1` class for another method which references my other trigger `Trigger2`? Because I am not sure if it will still work if i add `createObject4()` inside the `afterInsert()` method.

Comment: @Gaynerys It should be one TriggerHandler class per SObject. But you should put all of your triggers under one SObject into one single class.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put the logic inside another class, like

```
public class TriggerUtilClass {
public static TriggerBefore(List<Object1__c> triggerNew) {
    List<Object3__c> obj3List = new List<Object3__c>();
    for(Object1__c o1 : triggerNew) {
        Object3__c obj3form = new Object3__c();

        if(o1.Id != null) {

            obj3form.Name = o1.Field1__c;
            obj3form.Field3__c = o1.Object1__c; 
            obj3form.Field4__c = o1.Field4__c;
            obj3List.add(obj3form);

        }    
    }

    insert obj3List;
    }

}
```

And in your first trigger you state

```
if(Trigger.IsInsert) { 
    TriggerUtilClass.TriggerBefore(Trigger.new);
}
```

You should also look at this great [framework](https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework).

By the way, it is not best practice to assume your trigger is only fired on one record like you do in `Object1__c form1 = [SELECT Id, Field1__c FROM Object1__c WHERE Id =: Trigger.New[0].Object1__c];`
You should be rather using `for (Object1__c form1 : [SELECT Id, Field1__c FROM Object1__c WHERE Id  in : Trigger.New.keys()]) { }`

Comment: I'd avoid naming the method `TriggerBefore` because it implies all before logic should be placed in that method.  Ideally you'd have many methods that can be used in the before trigger.

Comment: what must I put inside `for (Object1__c form1 : [SELECT Id, Field1__c FROM Object1__c WHERE Id  in : Trigger.New.keys()]) { }`? I tried to use your suggestion but it doesn't recognize `form1.Field1__c` in my next query `List<Object3__c> form3 = [SELECT Id FROM Object3__c WHERE Name =: form1.Field1__c];`