# Finding the loop causing too many SOQL queries?

Tags: trigger, governorlimits

I've been tasked to create a Task trigger that updates account and lead fields with certain information when criteria are met on a trigger, including a custom "rollup summary field".  This seems to work most of the time, however I did run into an error today and have been unable to figure out what exactly is causing more than 100 SOQL queries to fire on a single record. I am not using Data Loader, but merely editing a single task record in the UI, yet am receiving the "Too Many SOQL Queries" error.  Any advice on how to track this down would be awesome!

Here is my trigger:

```
trigger trgSiteVisits on Task (after insert, after update, after delete)  
{ 
    List<Id> siteVisitAccountIds = new List<Id>();

    List<String> siteVisitAccountNames = new List<String>();

    List<Account> siteVisitAccounts = new List<Account>();
    List<Lead> siteVisitLeads = new List<Lead>();

    List<AggregateResult> visitCountAcct = new List<AggregateResult>();

    if(!Trigger.isDelete)
    {
        for(Task t : Trigger.new)
        {
            if(t.WhatId != null && String.ValueOf(t.WhatId).startsWith('001'))
            {
                if(t.Subject == 'Site Visit')
                {
                    siteVisitAccountIds.add(t.WhatId);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(Trigger.isDelete)
    {
        for(Task t : Trigger.old)
        {
            if(t.WhatId != null && String.ValueOf(t.WhatId).startsWith('001'))
            {
                if(t.Subject == 'Site Visit')
                {
                    siteVisitAccountIds.add(t.WhatId);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(siteVisitAccountIds.size() > 0)
    {
        siteVisitAccounts = [Select Id, Name from Account where Id =: siteVisitAccountIds];
        for(Account a : siteVisitAccounts)
        {
            siteVisitAccountNames.add(a.Name);
            a.Site_visit_by_Guild__c = true;
        }
        update siteVisitAccounts;

        siteVisitLeads = [Select Id, Company, Store_Location__c from Lead where Company =: siteVisitAccountNames or Store_Location__c =: siteVisitAccountNames]; 
        if(siteVisitLeads.size() > 0)
        {
            for(Lead l : siteVisitLeads)
            {
                l.Store_Visited_by_Guild__c = true;
            }
            update siteVisitLeads;
        }

        visitCountAcct = [Select WhatId, Count(Id) from Task where WhatId in : siteVisitAccountIds Group By WhatId];

        if(visitCountAcct.size() > 0)
        {
            for(AggregateResult ar : visitCountAcct)
            {
                if(siteVisitAccounts.size() > 0)
                {
                    for(Account a: siteVisitAccounts)
                    {
                        if(ar.get('WhatId') == a.Id)
                        {
                            a.Field_Marketing_Visits__c = Decimal.ValueOf(String.ValueOf(ar.get('expr0')));
                        }
                    }
                    update siteVisitAccounts;

                    for(Lead l: siteVisitLeads)
                    {
                        Account acctUpdater = [Select Id, Name, Field_Marketing_Visits__c from Account where Name =: l.Company or Name =: l.Store_location__c LIMIT 1];
                        if(l.Company == acctUpdater.Name || l.Store_location__c == acctUpdater.Name)
                        {
                            l.Field_Marketing_Visits__c = acctUpdater.Field_Marketing_Visits__c;
                        }
                    }
                    update siteVisitLeads;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(Account a: siteVisitAccounts)
            {
                a.Field_Marketing_Visits__c = 0;
                a.Site_visit_by_Guild__c = false;
            }

            for(Lead l : siteVisitLeads)
            {
                l.Field_Marketing_Visits__c = 0;
                l.Store_Visited_by_Guild__c = false;
            }

            update siteVisitAccounts;
            update siteVisitLeads;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's this one: `Account acctUpdater = [...]`. How to replace it is not immediately clear, though.

Comment: In addition to @AdrianLarson 's comment, also verify if you have triggers for Account and Leads that are running queries. I suggest you to bulkify your code, urgently ;) (DML/SQL)

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson I commented out that section and the exception went away.  Can I ask how you knew that was the offending query?  This specific part of the trigger isn't strictly necessary, I may also be able to use a formula field to pull this information automatically from the account record.

Comment: @krisuvik queries inside of loops are almost always the problem. If you have a loop, there should be no queries or DML statements inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I optimized your code (and fixed your issue) from Line 40 to the end of your trigger. Below is the code:

```
if(siteVisitAccountIds.size() > 0)
{
    siteVisitAccounts = [Select Id, Name from Account where Id =: siteVisitAccountIds];
    for(Account a : siteVisitAccounts)
    {
        siteVisitAccountNames.add(a.Name);
        a.Site_visit_by_Guild__c = true;
    }
    //update siteVisitAccounts;

    siteVisitLeads = [Select Id, Company, Store_Location__c from Lead where Company =: siteVisitAccountNames or Store_Location__c =: siteVisitAccountNames]; 
    if(siteVisitLeads.size() > 0)
    {
        for(Lead l : siteVisitLeads)
        {
            l.Store_Visited_by_Guild__c = true;
        }
        //update siteVisitLeads;
    }

    visitCountAcct = [Select WhatId, Count(Id) from Task where WhatId in : siteVisitAccountIds Group By WhatId];

    if(visitCountAcct.size() > 0)
    {
        //Bulkification part, gathering List<Account> info
        Set<String> validNameSet = new Set<String>();

        for(Lead l: siteVisitLeads) 
        {
            validNameSet.add(l.Company);
            validNameSet.add(l.Store_Location__c);
        }
        List<Account> acctUpdaterList = [Select  Id, Name, Field_Marketing_Visits__c 
                                            from Account 
                                            where Name in: validNameSet];
        for(AggregateResult ar : visitCountAcct)
        {
            if(siteVisitAccounts.size() > 0)
            {
                for(Account a: siteVisitAccounts)
                {
                    if(ar.get('WhatId') == a.Id)
                    {
                        a.Field_Marketing_Visits__c = Decimal.ValueOf(String.ValueOf(ar.get('expr0')));
                    }
                }
                //update siteVisitAccounts;

                for(Lead l: siteVisitLeads)
                {
                    //Retrieving related acctUpdater; 
                    Account acctUpdater;
                    for(Account a: acctUpdaterList) 
                    {
                        if(a.Name == l.Company || a.Name == l.Store_location__c) 
                        {
                            acctUpdater = a; 
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    if(acctUpdater != null)
                    {
                        l.Field_Marketing_Visits__c = acctUpdater.Field_Marketing_Visits__c;
                    }
                }
                //update siteVisitLeads;
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        for(Account a: siteVisitAccounts)
        {
            a.Field_Marketing_Visits__c = 0;
            a.Site_visit_by_Guild__c = false;
        }

        for(Lead l : siteVisitLeads)
        {
            l.Field_Marketing_Visits__c = 0;
            l.Store_Visited_by_Guild__c = false;
        }

        /*update siteVisitAccounts;
        update siteVisitLeads;*/
    }
    //those two updates will be executed in either scenarios
    update siteVisitAccounts;
    update siteVisitLeads;
}
```

I have explained in the comments where I did the bulkification.

A few suggestions to you:

1. You really need to understand bulkification in order to write quality Apex code. Here is a brief explanation: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code
2. Consider using a Trigger handler mechanism. Or separate your business logic outside your trigger. Related question: [Conversion From Apex Trigger to Apex Class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/142527/conversion-from-apex-trigger-to-apex-class/142528#142528)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I've seen the bulkification page before, and I had thought I was adhering to those best practices (or at least trying) by using lists instead of single records.  I'll look into this again.  I'll also look into using a Trigger handler.